# Is it possible to have a program detect when a picture is taken on the iPhone and then grab that picture?

Tags: iphone, camera

I am trying to create an app that will allow my program to detect when a picture is taken with the built in iphone camera and then automatically send that picture to my server.  Is that something that is possible to do or would I need to build my own camera in my program to accomplish this?  If it is possible, can someone please provide me with that information.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to write your own camera app.  Backgrounding (at least in non-jailbroken apps) isn't useful the way you might expect working with more reasonable systems.

You should be able to grab all the photos taken, see which ones are new, and upload those to the server - it just won't be an automatic process as the user will need to open your app after closing the camera.

Answer (score 0):

yes friend ..for this you have to use imagepicker

-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

```
if((UIButton *) sender == getimage) {
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedcamera;
}   
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

}

and to send it to server you have to use asihttpconnection delegate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the camera in your app you can make use of [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070) and then make the `sourceType` as

```
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
```

You must also implement the [UIImagePickerControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007069) which will provide you the image taken from the camera.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController  *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary  *)info
{
// Some code
}
```